# Chdsk does not work: found.000 folder is not created again after deletion

Tags: hard-drive

My external hard drive (WS Passport) has crashed lately. All folders turned into white unknown objects, each 0KB. I ran chdsk and got all the files restored. I was able to access the found.000 folder on my father's pc, but not on mine. After several futile attempts to access it from my laptop, I decided to delete it and run chdsk again. I did so. Now, the chdsk refuses to do the trick one more time. No found.000 folder is now created upon completion of the recovery procedure!

My question is: how come? Is there an explanation as to why chdsk does not create a found.000 folder anymore? Is there any way to force chdsk to create it?

According to the disk manager, the data (around 1.5 TB) is seemingly still there. I'd love to recover at least some of it.

Comment: You have a very broken concept of how chkdsk works.  It is not a data recovery tool, it is a filesystem consistency check.  The `found.000` was created in the process of fixing the inconsistencies in the filesystem.  After chkdsk completed, everything is consistent, and so running it again will not find the same inconsistencies or create new `found.000`.

Comment: You should reverse the deletiion of found.000, any data contained within that, will be lost if you don't.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Ramhound! At least, now I know what is what. Can you recommend a couple of trusted tools for recoverng the deleted files?

Comment: @slowburner this is meant for pictures, but it recovers all files and has worked very well for me in the past for recovering deleted files http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: By the way, what does Ramhound exactly mean by "reversing the deletiion of found.000"? Using a data recovery tool? Or is there any other way to "reverse" the deletion?

Comment: Simplest would just be to bin the drive & recover to a fresh one from your last backup.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't have a backup.

Comment: Is there any tool that can recover not only data but also an original folder structure? (windows 7, NTFS)

Comment: No. File recovery is just that - they recover files by file type, no names, just file001.jpg etc, no folder structure -  unless you're very lucky. Next time... have a backup; that's what they're for :/

Comment: [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](//superuser.com/q/241817)